# SQL Server: Nested cursor syntax error

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I tried to define following SQL Server nested cursor statement: I loop calendars and migrate them from cut_calendar to sd_calendar. Each calendar also have calendar days. They are also moved by each calendar move.

```
 DECLARE @id NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @sdCalendarId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @calendarTypId NUMERIC(5)
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(35)
    DECLARE @description NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @ptyId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @lockCode NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @dataOwnerId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @cntId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysMonday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysTuesday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysWednesday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysThursday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysFriday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysSaturday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysSunday CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @ccyId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @version NUMERIC(10)
    DECLARE @seal VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @lstUpdTs DATETIME
    DECLARE @day_id NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @day_calDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @day_lockCode NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @day_calComment NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @day_dataOwnerId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @day_calendarId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @day_calRecurring CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @day_version NUMERIC(10)
    DECLARE @day_seal VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @day_lstUpdTs DATETIME
    DECLARE @day_sdCalendarDaysId NUMERIC(20)
    DECLARE @sdCodeId NUMERIC(20)


    DECLARE cursorCutoffCalendar CURSOR FOR
      SELECT ID, NAME, CALENDAR_TYP_ID,DESCRIPTION,PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS
      FROM CUT_CALENDAR
      WHERE ID != 1

    OPEN cursorCutoffCalendar
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCutoffCalendar INTO @id, @name, @calendarTypId, @description, @ptyId, @lockCode, @dataOwnerId, @cntId, @nonBusinessDaysMonday, @nonBusinessDaysTuesday, @nonBusinessDaysWednesday, @nonBusinessDaysThursday, @nonBusinessDaysFriday, @nonBusinessDaysSaturday, @nonBusinessDaysSunday, @ccyId, @code, @version, @seal, @lstUpdTs
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sdCalendarId = COALESCE(MAX(ID),1) FROM SD_CALENDAR
        SET @sdCalendarId = @sdCalendarId + 1

        UPDATE CUT_CALENDAR_DAY
        SET CALENDAR_ID = @sdCalendarId
        WHERE CALENDAR_ID = @id

        SELECT @sdCodeId = ID FROM SD_CALENDAR WHERE CODE = @code
        IF @sdCodeId > 0
            SET @code = CONCAT(@code, '_co')
        ELSE

        INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR (ID, NAME, CALENDAR_ROLE_ID,DESCRIPTION,USE_IN_CUTOFF,PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS)
        VALUES(@sdCalendarId, @name, @calendarTypId,@description,1,@ptyId,@lockCode,@dataOwnerId,@cntId,@nonBusinessDaysMonday,@nonBusinessDaysTuesday,@nonBusinessDaysWednesday,@nonBusinessDaysThursday,@nonBusinessDaysFriday,@nonBusinessDaysSaturday,@nonBusinessDaysSunday,@ccyId,@code,@version,@seal,@lstUpdTs)

        DECLARE cursorCutoffCalendarDays CURSOR FOR
          SELECT ID, CAL_DATE, LOCK_CODE,CAL_COMMENT,DATA_OWNER_ID,CALENDAR_ID,CAL_RECURRING,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS
          FROM CUT_CALENDAR_DAY
          WHERE ID != 1

        OPEN cursorCutoffCalendarDays
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCutoffCalendarDays INTO @day_id, @day_calDate, @day_lockCode, @day_calComment, @day_dataOwnerId, @day_calendarId, @day_calRecurring, @day_version, @day_seal, @day_lstUpdTs
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @day_sdCalendarDaysId = COALESCE(MAX(ID),1) FROM SD_CALENDAR_DAY
            SET @day_sdCalendarDaysId = @day_sdCalendarDaysId + 1

            INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR_DAY (ID, CAL_DATE, LOCK_CODE,CAL_COMMENT,DATA_OWNER_ID,CALENDAR_ID,CAL_RECURRING,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS)
            VALUES(@day_sdCalendarDaysId, @day_calDate, @day_lockCode, @day_calComment, @day_dataOwnerId, @day_calendarId, @day_calRecurring, @day_version, @day_seal, @day_lstUpdTs)


        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCutoffCalendarDays INTO @day_sdCalendarDaysId, @day_calDate, @day_lockCode, @day_calComment, @day_dataOwnerId, @day_calendarId, @day_calRecurring, @day_version, @day_seal, @day_lstUpdTs

        END
        CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
        DEALLOCATE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
        GO

        DELETE FROM CUT_CALENDAR
        WHERE ID = @id

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCutoffCalendar INTO @sdCalendarId, @name, @calendarTypId, @description, @ptyId, @lockCode, @dataOwnerId, @cntId, @nonBusinessDaysMonday, @nonBusinessDaysTuesday, @nonBusinessDaysWednesday, @nonBusinessDaysThursday, @nonBusinessDaysFriday, @nonBusinessDaysSaturday, @nonBusinessDaysSunday, @ccyId, @code, @version, @seal, @lstUpdTs

    END
    CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendar
    DEALLOCATE cursorCutoffCalendar
    GO
```

Now when I run this, I get following error:

> SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'cursorCutoffCalendarDays'.

cursorCutoffCalendarDays is the inner cursor of my statement.

Comment: What line is the error on? That would be a start. Having said that, instead of trying to debug this, your time would be better spent rewriting the process in a set based manner. I can see no reason that this shouldn't be two set based insert statements, rather than two cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing GO from:

```
    CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
    DEALLOCATE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
    GO
```

And I agree with the comment you got from GarethD, I used to write cursors like this but then I asked how to do it without the cursor and got a nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Remove Go from this line then try

```
 CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
 DEALLOCATE cursorCutoffCalendarDays
```